How can I download mod_authnz_sspi.so since its no more available on apachehaus?
I'm trying to get REMOTE_USER in the PHP header using Apache 2.4.
Can someone provide a mod_authnz_sspi.so file or link? The primary goal is to bypass the login screen using Windows credentials, thus not requiring any login.
I have tried using mod_authn_ntlm.so, but my XAMPP says it's not a valid Win32 application. Is there a way around this or some other module for a similar thing?

Windows uses .dll files, Linux/Unix uses .so

Assuming you are trying to use NTLM or SSPI on a Windows machine, you have to install the proper PHP extension depending on your PHP version. Run  phpinfo(); or php --version to determine if you are running a 32 or 64 bits PHP install.
Afterwards, you can download the appropriate NTLM 32 or 64 bits DLL extension directly from the Apache Hause's download page and enable it. Please note that .so files are modules for Linux, not for Windows.
I would not recommend you to use the SSPI extension for Windows because it more or less a fallback to the NTLM and, unless proven otherwise, no one has ever managed to make it work with Kerberos under Windows.
